# Aws Rds global event scheduler throws authentication error for super admin

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am running the following query on my aws RDS server :

`SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`

I am already super admin for that .

Still I get the following error :

```
Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For RDS, we don't have the super privileges. The user that we create during the launch of an RDS instance is not a superuser, it is restricted.

To change `event_scheduler` parameter you need to edit the corresponding parameter group of your RDS instance.

From the AWS RDS console goto 'parameter groups' click on the parameter group corresponding to your instance and search for 'event_scheduler'. You can change its value by clicking on 'edit parameters'.

After changing the parameter you need to check the parameter group is in sync with your instance, for that click on your RDS instance from your console goto configuration, there you can find your parameter group name and whether a restart is required to apply the changes you have done in the parameter group

Note:- If a single parameter group is associated with more than one instance, the changes in that parameter group will apply to all the instances associated with it.

Comment: Is there any specific parameter for that in parameter group ?

Comment: From the AWS RDS console goto 'parameter groups' click on the parameter group corresponding to your instance and search for 'event_scheduler'. You can change its value by clicking on 'edit parameters' (also updated the answer , please check)

Answer (score 1):

You might not have permissions in general to set these parameters in SQL directly.
Instead try to set the parameter `event_scheduler` to `ON` in the parameter group of your RDS instance.

For information about creating and modifying a DB parameter group, see Working with DB Parameter Groups [1].

[1] https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html

Comment: Is there any specific parameter in parameter groups which I have to enable to make it work?

Comment: As stated avbove, the parameter is called: ```event_scheduler```